# PostgreSQL update trigger Comparing Hstore values

Tags: postgresql, triggers, plpgsql, hstore

I am creating trigger in PostgresSQL. On update I would like to compare all of the values in a Hstore column and update changes in my mirror table. I managed to get names of my columns in variable `k` but I am not able to get values using it from `NEW` and `OLD`.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION function_replication() RETURNS TRIGGER AS
$BODY$
DECLARE
    k text;
BEGIN
        FOR k IN SELECT key FROM EACH(hstore(NEW)) LOOP
            IF NEW.k != OLD.k THEN
                EXECUTE 'UPDATE ' || TG_TABLE_NAME || '_2' || 'SET ' || k || '=' || new.k || ' WHERE ID=$1.ID;' USING OLD;
            END IF;
        END LOOP;
        RETURN NEW;
END;
$BODY$
language plpgsql;
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should operate on hstore representations of the records `new` and `old`. Also, use the [`format()`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-string.html#FUNCTIONS-STRING-FORMAT) function for better control and readibility.

```
create or replace function function_replication() 
returns trigger as
$body$
declare
    newh hstore = hstore(new);
    oldh hstore = hstore(old);
    key text;
begin
    foreach key in array akeys(newh) loop
        if newh->key != oldh->key then
            execute format(
                'update %s_2 set %s = %L where id = %s',
                tg_table_name, key, newh->key, oldh->'id');
        end if;
    end loop;
    return new;
end;
$body$
language plpgsql;
```

Comment: Using != is not 100% clean - it MySQL ism :). It is detail - what is worse - it is sensitive to NULL - in this context is better to use `IS DISTINCT FROM` or `IS NOT DISTINCT FROM`

Comment: You're right, my answer focused on how to access the columns of `new` and `old`. Also, the trigger should execute a single update, your version is more refined.

Answer (score 2):

Another version - with minimalistic numbers of updates - in partially functional design (where it is possible).
This trigger should be AFTER trigger, to be ensured correct behave.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION function_replication()
RETURNS trigger AS $$
DECLARE
  newh hstore;
  oldh hstore;
  update_vec text[];
  pair text[];
BEGIN
  IF new IS DISTINCT FROM old THEN
    IF new.id <> old.id THEN
      RAISE EXCEPTION 'id should be immutable';
    END IF;
    newh := hstore(new); oldh := hstore(old); update_vec := '{}';
    FOREACH pair SLICE 1 IN ARRAY hstore_to_matrix(newh - oldh)
    LOOP
      update_vec := update_vec || format('%I = %L', pair[1], pair[2]);
    END LOOP; 
    EXECUTE  
      format('UPDATE %I SET %s WHERE id = $1',
         tg_table_name || '_2',
         array_to_string(update_vec, ', '))
      USING old.id;
  END IF;
  RETURN NEW; -- the value is not important in AFTER trg 
END;
$$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;

CREATE TABLE foo(id int PRIMARY KEY, a int, b int);
CREATE TABLE foo_2(LIKE foo INCLUDING ALL);
CREATE TRIGGER xxx AFTER UPDATE ON foo
  FOR EACH ROW EXECUTE PROCEDURE function_replication();

INSERT INTO foo VALUES(1, NULL, NULL);
INSERT INTO foo VALUES(2, 1,1);
INSERT INTO foo_2 VALUES(1, NULL, NULL);
INSERT INTO foo_2 VALUES(2, 1,1);

UPDATE foo SET a = 20, b = 30 WHERE id = 1;
UPDATE foo SET a = NULL WHERE id = 1;
```

This code is little bit more complex, but all what should be escaped is escaped and reduce number of executed `UPDATE` commands. `UPDATE` is full SQL command and the overhead of full SQL commands should be significantly higher than code that reduce number of full SQL commands.